# iAP latest_receipt_info array which element shows the latest status

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am trying to get latest status for auto renewable subscription. [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH104-SW4) suggests to use `latest_receipt_info`. After you validate IAP receipt with iTunes, returned JSON has an array called `latest_receipt_info`. I searched but couldn't find a definite answer. I only have one type of subscription. Which element in this array shows the most recent subscription info? Is it the first, last or should I walk through each element and sort it out by myself?

Comment: Each item in that array should have an expiration date. You would need to find the one that hasn't expired yet. If there are none that haven't expired, then the user most likely cancelled their subscription. I'm not 100% sure, but I think the items in that array are sorted chronologically.

Comment: I know how to verify the receipt. However as you said I am not 100% sure about the order of transactions. I guess I will walk though each element and sort the items according to purchase date and decide afterwards.

Comment: @Meanteacher did you find the answer on this?